# Debugging with NSZombieEnabled

Tags: cocoa

I have been tracing a BAD_ACCESS error using NSZombieEnabled. As error I get returned:

```
*** -[MyDocument respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x2671b0
```

I do know what this means,however what surprises me is that I don't call this function anywhere, not in MyDocument.m nor in any imported files.To be exact, I don't call this at all in my whole project. The debugger will not go to the actual code that causes the error, but only shows the assembly code, which, when I click on it, gives me and even bigger list of not understandable numbers.

Does anyone have an idea where this weird "respondsToSelector" could come from? Maybe from frameworks I am using? I am really confused.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: solved issue.Tested which dealloc caused the error and removed it.It now works fine.I am still surprised where it got the "respondsToSelector" from though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`respondsToSelector:` is widely used in frameworks. For instance, if your class is a delegate or data source (highly likely for MyDocument) the delegating object will use it to determine which delegate methods you support.

In general, the way to find out where a problem like this is happening is to set a breakpoint on `objc_exception_throw()` (Run->Show->Breakpoints, double-click where it says “Double-Click for Symbol”, type `objc_exception_throw`) and run under the debugger (Build->Build and Debug - Breakpoints On).